# Tkinter : Button in frame not visible

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to implement a TicTacToe program. I am an absolute beginner in python. After viewing many tutorials and reading a few books, I have understood the basics of Python. I'm trying to get the buttons to display in a frame, but all I get is a blank window.

[link for image of the resultant window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P2jk.png)

This is the code I have so far:

```python
from Tkinter import *

class Buttons(object):

    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button1= Button(frame,text="1",height=4,width=8,command=self.move)
        self.button1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button2= Button(frame,text="2",height=4,width=8,command=self.move)
        self.button2.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button3= Button(frame,text="3",height=4,width=8,command=self.move)
        self.button3.pack(side=LEFT)


root = Tk()
root=mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay,I understood the problem,needed to put b=Buttons(root) for it to work. It would be helpful if explained why this was required? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined your `Buttons` class but you didn't create an instance of that class, so no buttons were actually constructed. Also, you had a typo / syntax error:

```
root=mainloop()
```

should be

```
root.mainloop()
```

Also, you didn't define the `move` callback method.

Here's a repaired version of your code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Buttons(object):

    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button1 = Button(frame, text="1", height=4, width=8, command=self.move)
        self.button1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button2 = Button(frame, text="2", height=4, width=8, command=self.move)
        self.button2.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button3 = Button(frame, text="3", height=4, width=8, command=self.move)
        self.button3.pack(side=LEFT)

    def move(self):
        print "click!"

root = Tk()
Buttons(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However, this still has a problem: The `move` method has no way of knowing which button called it. Here's one way to fix that. I've also changed

```
from Tkinter import *
```

to

```
import tkinter as tk
```

It's not a good idea to use "star" imports. They make code harder to read and they pollute your namespace with all the names defined in the imported module (that's 175 names in the case of Tkinter), which can lead to name collisions.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Buttons(object):

    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(1, 4):
            button = tk.Button(
                frame, text=i, height=4, width=8, 
                command=lambda n=i:self.move(n)
            )
            button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            self.buttons.append(button)

    def move(self, n):
        print "click", n

root = tk.Tk()
Buttons(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much for this post! It is immensely helpful!

Comment: @ms: My pleasure! Good luck with your program. You will probably find it easier to build your tic-tac-toe grid using the `.grid` method instead of `.pack`.

Comment: yes,I am on to that already. I am pretty sure to face a lot of bumps once i start implementing the gaming portion. Hopefully SO will help me through it :D thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was I needed to add a variable at the end of the code. Something like b=Buttons(root). It's working now.